# Removing the title-bar of a UTILTY window - JavaFX

Tags: javafx

Is it possible to remove the title-bar of a utility stage window in JavaFX?

The stage has been initialized as:

```
primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.UTILITY);
```

I must set the StageStyle as "**UTILITY**" only, because I don't want a Java Coffee icon displaying in the windows taskbar.

Comment: Is your stage, whose title bar you want to remove along with applying the `UTILITY` stage style, a **Secondary Stage** ?

Comment: No, its the primary stage .. it's on the top most